# How do you insert a variable into CreateDirectory()

Tags: c++, create-directory

Is there a way to insert a string variable into CreateDirectory? I want it to create a directory in C: with the name the user has entered. When I do something like

```
CreateDirectory ("C:\\" << newname, NULL);
```

My compiler gives me the error "No match   for operator<< in 'C:\ << newname'"

This is my code. The problem is in void newgame().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

int a;
string newname;

string savepath;

struct game
{
    string name;
    int checkpoint;
    int level;
};

void wait( time_t delay )
{
time_t timer0, timer1;
time( &timer0 );
do {
time( &timer1 );
} while (( timer1 - timer0 ) < delay );
}

void error()
{
    cout << "\nError, bad input." << endl;
}
void options()
{
    cout << "No options are currently implemented." << endl;
}
void load()
{
    cout << "Load a Game:\n";
}
//This is where I'm talking about.
void newgame()
{
    cout << "Name your Game:\n";
    getline(cin,newname);
    cin.get();
    game g1;
    g1.name=newname;
    //I want it to create a dir in C: with the name the user has entered.
    //How can I do it?
    CreateDirectory ("C:\\" << newname, NULL);


}
//This isn't the whole piece of code, just most of it, I can post the rest if needed
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CreateDirectory (("C:\\" + newname).c_str(), NULL);
```

You can join `std::string`s with `operator+`. Or, in your case, you can join a C string to an `std::string` using `operator+`, also. The result is an `std::string`. (Be careful though -- you cannot join two C strings together that way.)

I suspect, however, that `CreateDirectory` takes a C string, not a `std::string`, so you'll need to convert it with the `.c_str()` member.

Comment: Win32 API params are LPCSTR or LPSTR typically. That's (const) pointer to CHAR* or WCHAR* depending on the compile options (Unicode or not)

Answer (score 0):

To use stream insertion, you need to first create a stream:

```
std::ostringstream buffer;

buffer << "c:\\" << newname;

CreateDirectory(buffer.str().c_str());
```